# No pictures in the People Search Core Results web part

Tags: people-search

I've added a People Search Core Results web part to a page and I do a search for specific users with a fixed keyword query. It displays the names and info correctly but it doesn't display the picture. All that is shown is a red X. If I log on to the server with the service account the pictures are displayed. I'm guessing this has something to do with the permissions to the MySite web application but I'm not sure how I should go about fixing it so the pictures are displayed aswell.

Comment: What version of SharePoint? How did you add the pictures? Does the out of the box People Search page show the pictures? Is the My Site Host in the same Web App as the Search Page?

Comment: This was an issue I had in 2010 environment, it resolved itself "magically", no idea why it just decided to work but it could be work behind the scenes (read: network secs) that I did not know of but nevertheless it was resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:
It resolved itself "magically", no idea why it just decided to work but it could be work behind the scenes (read: network sec) that I did not know of but nevertheless it was resolved.